# Disable an #include instruction in sudoers

Tags: sudo, sudoers, comments

Can a sudoers #include instruction be disabled with an additional # character?
Or rather just delete the leading # character?

(I wish I would understand what the sudo developers had on their mind when they created an instruction that requires a leading comment character.)

Comment: In general case the rationale may be like this: You invent an optional extension to the format. You design its directives so they are invisible (look like comments) to old/basic parsers that don't support them, but new/"enlightened" parsers benefit. Compare [extended M3U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#Extended_M3U) or `#EXTVLCOPT`. I doubt this is the case for `sudoers` though, this file must be strict. Probably someone mindlessly mimicked `#include` from C preprocessor, where it's OK because `#` is not a comment. In `sudoers` comments start with `#` and `#include` is bad design really.

Comment: The first time I analyzed my `sudoers` file I thought `include` is a directive and `#include` is a *commented* directive. The rule of least surprise violated hard. Also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244265/108618).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a line starting with `##include` would be a comment and not an include. See `man sudoers`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` command that will disable the directive:

```bsh
sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g'
```

What happens with the above code:

- The `sed` command disables the `#includedir` directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override the `/etc/sudoers` file.